# Incoming calling Notification in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-notifications

Hello everyone I am trying to make an incoming call Notification like WhatsApp which has 2 buttons and the notification is on top until the button action has not been performed can some please provide the code for it for Android studio

I want the output like this
[image]